# Manually coded Poisson log likelihood function returns a different result from glm for interactive models

Tags: r, regression, glm, poisson

I've coded my own Poisson likelihood function, but it is returning values that are significantly different from glm for a model with an interaction for a specific data. Notice that the function spits out exactly the same result as glm from all other data I've tried, as well as for the model without the interaction for this data.

```
> # Log likelihood function
> llpoi = function(X, y){
+   # Ensures X is a matrix
+   if(class(X) != "matrix") X = as.matrix(X)
+   # Ensures there's a constant
+   if(sum(X[, 1]) != nrow(X)) X = cbind(1, X)  
+   # A useful scalar that I'll need below
+   k = ncol(X)
+   ## Function to be maximized
+   FUN = function(par, X, y){
+     # beta hat -- the parameter we're trying to estimate
+     betahat = par[1:k]
+     # mu hat -- the systematic component
+     muhat = X %*% betahat
+     # Log likelihood function
+     sum(muhat * y - exp(muhat))
+   }
+   # Optimizing
+   opt = optim(rep(0, k), fn = FUN, y = y, X = X, control = list(fnscale = -1), method = "BFGS", hessian = T)
+   # Results, including getting the SEs from the hessian
+ cbind(opt$par, sqrt(diag(solve(-1 * opt$hessian))))
+ }
> 
> # Defining inputs 
> y = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 0)
> x1 = c(8, 1, 0, 3, 3, 3, 5, 4, 0.4, 1.5, 2, 1, 1, 7, 2, 3, 0, 2, 1.5, 5, 1, 4, 5.5, 6, 3, 3, 2, 0.5, 5, 10, 3, 22, 20, 3, 20, 10, 15, 25, 15, 6, 3.5, 5, 18, 2, 15.0, 16, 24)
> x2 = c(12, 12, 12, 16, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 9, 9, 12, 9, 12, 12, 9, 16, 9, 6, 12, 9, 9, 12, 12, 12, 12, 14, 14, 14, 9, 12, 9, 12, 3, 12, 9, 6, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 9)
> 
> # Results
> withmyfun = llpoi(cbind(x1, x2, x1 * x2), y)
> round(withmyfun, 2)
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]  0.96 0.90
[2,] -0.05 0.09
[3,] -0.02 0.08
[4,]  0.00 0.01
> withglm = glm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x1 * x2, family = "poisson")
> round(summary(withglm)$coef[, 1:2], 2)
            Estimate Std. Error
(Intercept)     1.08       0.90
x1             -0.07       0.09
x2             -0.03       0.08
x1:x2           0.00       0.01
```

Is this something data specific? Is it inherent to the 
optimization process, which will eventually diverge more significantly from glm and I just got unlucky with this data? Is it a function of using method = "BFGS" for optim?

Comment: this question will likely get better answers from the Cross Validated Stack because the question is more about statistical context than R code.

Comment: You're right. Can I move the question, or only a moderator can do that?

Comment: I would copy and paste it there. I have some editing powers, but not that many. Sorry!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After much research, I learned that the two results differ because glm.fit, the workhorse behind glm optimizes the function through Newton-Raphson method, while I used BFGS in my llpoi function. BFGS is faster, but less precise. The two results will be very similar on most cases, but may differ more significantly when the surface area is too flat or has too many maxima, as correctly pointed out by amatsuo_net, because the climbing algorithm used by BFGS will get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

By rescaling the right-hand side variables, the outcome improves a lot.

```
> library(data.table)
> setDT(tmp)
> tmp[, x1 := scale(x1)][, x2 := scale(x2)]
> 
> 
> withmyfun = with(tmp, llpoi(cbind(x1, x2, x1 * x2), y))
> withmyfun
[,1]      [,2]
[1,]  0.57076392 0.1124637
[2,] -0.19620040 0.1278070
[3,] -0.01509032 0.1169019
[4,]  0.05636459 0.1380611
> 
> withglm = glm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x1 * x2, family = "poisson", data = tmp)
> summary(withglm)$coef[, 1:2]
Estimate Std. Error
(Intercept)  0.57075132  0.1124641
x1          -0.19618199  0.1278061
x2          -0.01507467  0.1169034
x1:x2        0.05636934  0.1380621
>
```

So, my recommendation is, inside `llpoi`, to have a procedure to normalize the variables before using `optim` to the data and rescale the estimates based before the function returns the value. Your example data have too big range, which results in very small estimates of coefficients. This problem gets worse because of the relatively flat likelihood surface because of insignificant variables.

**Note:**

You can get very close outputs from this except for the intercept. What I meant by standardizing is something like that.

```
  llpoi = function(X, y){
  # Ensures X is a matrix
  if(class(X) != "matrix") X = as.matrix(X)
  # Ensures there's a constant
  if(sum(X[, 1]) != nrow(X)) X = cbind(1, X)  
  # A useful scalar that I'll need below
  avgs <- c(0, apply(X[, 2:ncol(X)], 2, mean))
  sds <- c(1, apply(X[, 2:ncol(X)], 2, sd))
  X<- t((t(X) - avgs)/sds)

  k = ncol(X)
  ## Function to be maximized
  FUN = function(par, X, y){
    # beta hat -- the parameter we're trying to estimate
    betahat = par[1:k]
    # mu hat -- the systematic component
    muhat = X %*% betahat
    # Log likelihood function
    sum(muhat * y - exp(muhat))
  }
  # Optimizing

  opt = optim(rep(0, k), fn = FUN, y = y, X = X, control = list(fnscale = -1), method = "BFGS", hessian = T)
  # Results, including getting the SEs from the hessian
  cbind(opt$par, sqrt(diag(solve(-1 * opt$hessian))))/sds
}
```

Comment: I'm less concerned with model fit (in fact I know that this is a pretty terrible model) than with glm replicability. I'd like to understand why the results are so different and how to minimize the difference, regardless of the data.

Comment: "how to minimize the difference" is what I'm talking about. You need to normalize (which I mean standardize) the data before using `optim` in your function if you want to get the result similar to `glm`. What I have shown in the code is that by standardizing the variables outside function, you can get very similar result because, for such well-formatted data, `llpoi` behaves as good as `glm`. Why you need to standardize the data could be found other places (e.g. https://www.biomedware.com/files/documentation/Preparing_data/Why_standardize_variables.htm)

Comment: But notice that, unless the user also standardizes the data before calling glm, including a standardization within llpoi won't solve my problem; the results won't be almost identical for glm and llpoi, which is what I seek.